How to import my fastq files into qiime2?
I recieved some Illumina amplicon sequencing (16S) fastq files that I have ton analyze. I tried to import them into QIIME2 to work on a qza file, but I couldn't manage to do it.
Here's the code I'm using :
qiime tools import \                                                                                                                                                                emiliendirosa@Mac
  --type "SampleData[PairedEndSequencesWithQuality]" \
  --input-path data/ \
  --output-path reads_qza/reads.qza \
  --input-format CasavaOneEightSingleLanePerSampleDirFmt

Here's the error :
There was a problem importing data/:
Missing one or more files for CasavaOneEightSingleLanePerSampleDirFmt: '.+_.+_L[0-9][0-9][0-9]_R[12]_001\.fastq\.gz'
And you'll find attached a screenshot of my files. I believe that the files naming syntax is causing the error, but I have no idea on how to fix it.
fastq files
Any help is appreciated ! :)
